# No such table exists: Customers

Tags: python, database, sqlite, insert

```
db = sqlite3.connect("N:\WORK\Computing 4 Coursework\StockDataBaseSystem.db")
db.execute("CREATE TABLE Customers (Title str, FirstName str, LastName str, HouseNumber int, StreetName str, PostCode str, City str, PhoneNumber str, CustomerID str)")
db.execute("create table Products (ProductName text, Price int, Profit int, Sold int, InStock int, Size int, ProductID text)")
db.execute("create table Orders (TotalPrice float, TotalProfit float, DateOrdered date, DateDelivered date, QuantityOrdered int, OrderID text)")
db.commit()
```

My program is basically a GUI database software which allows to add customer details onto a database, everything works fine up to the point where it states 'No such table exists: Customers' whem I try to add a value onto a database. I have checked if I have not dropped the table somewhere but no I havent (Guessing that is good). My other 'Products' and 'Orders' table have been created on the database but not the Customers one which I find weird because the code is the same.. I would put the whole program up here but right now it is around 300 lines.

Comment: Does SQLite 3 support the `str` type in columns?  The classic SQL types would be `CHAR(n)` or `VARCHAR(n)` or variants on that theme, where `n` is a number you'd supply verbatim (e.g. 32) as you execute the CREATE TABLE statement. Did you check the error returns from any of the statements — and if not, as your code suggests, why not?

Comment: So technical, sorry I am not so good with SQL, its for a computing project. I am sure that SQlite3 supports strings in columns, the error actually comes from a statement where i try to add values to the 'Customer' table but obviously because it 'Doesnt Exist' apparently then it can't be done. Im not too sure about what you mean with the varchar etc as im not so good on sql and i just know the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

str is not a data type for strings in sqlite. You will want to use text instead.

https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: Okay cheers, I guess this sorted another problem with the program but I still receive the same error.

Comment: So changing "db.execute("CREATE TABLE Customers (Title str, FirstName str, LastName str, HouseNumber int, StreetName str, PostCode str, City str, PhoneNumber str, CustomerID str)")" to "db.execute("CREATE TABLE Customers (Title text, FirstName text, LastName text, HouseNumber text, StreetName text, PostCode text, City text, PhoneNumber text, CustomerID text)")" still resulted in the table not being created?